# Can't Train SSD Inception-V2 with Larger Input Resolution with TensorFlow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am looking to use the TensorFlow Object Detection API to train SSD Inception-V2 from scratch on a custom dataset with resolution larger than 300x300.

I am referencing this as a sample config file: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config

I have successfully trained a 4-class custom model with okay performance by setting:
`num_classes: 4` and pointing the training data path to my custom dataset.

However, the input resolution was set to 300x300 with:

```
image_resizer {
  fixed_shape_resizer {
    height: 300
    width: 300
  }
}
```

My dataset has pretty small objects and I want to increase the input resolution during training.

However, If I just change this setting to:

```
image_resizer {
  fixed_shape_resizer {
    height: 640
    width: 640
  }
}
```

The model does not train at all and the loss stays stagnate. I saw a few other threads that talked about changing the anchor boxes and customizing the SSD network to be compatible with the new resolution.

I have tried several configurations of anchor boxes and model customizations but I can never get the model training. (It looks like its training but the loss doesnt go down and the inference is garbage outputs)

Has anyone trained SSD Inception-V2 with the TensorFlow object detection API on resolution other than 300x300 and can supply more concrete steps to execute the training?

Answer (score 0):

The original [SSD paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.02325.pdf) that came out in 2016 was designed with 2 specific input image sizes, `300x300` and `512x512`. However, the backbone for that was Mobilenet (considering speed as the main factor). You can try resizing the images to `512x512` and then training. However, considering that the repo has `300x300` as the default value would probably mean that the model works best when the inputs are of that size and not any other.

There are however many other models that allow an input size of `640x640`

In Tensorflow models zoo - version 1, you have `ssd_resnet50_v1` [config file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync.config) and in [version 2](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md), you have many other variants of SSD and EfficientDet which support `640x640` (with different backbones however).

You will probably get better results by training using the above-mentioned models

Answer (score 0):

Because you have small objects in your data I propose you try to subsample your 640x640 pictures this way;

[image]

...where the "black 640x640" is your original image. And when you know the tricks you can easily get by random location sampling 300x300 images (illustrated by blue, green, red rectangles above) to make a reliable presentation of your original from this image, directly compatible for the SSD-Inception V2. Perhaps you could make reliable object recognition this way? Both training and inferencing.

Another approach to utilize the "full profound intelligence of the well known backbone SSD-Inception V2 but only for 300x300 input images" would be parallel splitting of your image in the following way; [image]

...meaning you would configure static locations for 300x300 size input images for parallel copies of SSD Inceptions-V2. And, apply simple "count-logic" e.g. to calculate total number of small objects in the original 640x640 image.

I hope those ideas would help you to resolve your original problem.